# best way to use url POST from android app

Tags: android, http-post

I was working with sending and receiving data in json format between server and my app and everything was fine. But today I needed to change de language in a url site loaded in a WebView. I needed to post "lang" and DeviceLanguage pair to the site hosted in a server to show the site accordingly. I discovered you don't need to use the doInBackground and other methods to accomplish the task, just this

```
byte[] post = EncodingUtils.getBytes("lang="+DeviceLanguage,"BASE64");
MainActivity.myWebView.postUrl("http://myownsite.com/info.php", post);
```

and I get what I want. My question is: is it so simple like that? what things I didn't take into account?. Must I use try and catch ? is there any security matters ?

Comment: are you using that webview to display the site? (if so, then yes, your solution is fine)

Comment: from what I gather in your question, this is setting a cookie in the webview so that the rest of the navigation on this site (still in the webview) is done in the new language. If this is the case, these 2 lines are, afaik, the easiest way to do so. However, shouldn't there be a button already somewhere on the site to change the language? In which case, you could also either leave the possibility to the user to do that themselves, or use some javascript to trigger that button. Also, @juanlugm's answer is fine in the general case where you are making an Http request and reading the answer

Answer (score 0):

OK, if you use Webview you are creating a View and the WebKit rendering engine for nothing. 
I think that you should not overhead your app with this kind of code.

IMHO you should use AsyncTask for this.
    public class SubmitAsync extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... data) {
       HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
       HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
       HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
       HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
       HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://www.yourweb.com");
       List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", Double.toString((Double) data[0])));
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name1", Double.toString((Double) data[1])));
       ...
       request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
       HttpResponse response=client.execute(request);
       ...
```

Comment: I hope do not be offensive but @njzk2 (17K) says the two lines of code above is enough. I think that if you don't need to connect to a DB, just send a byte of data then it is not necessary the doInBackground method. In other hand, I've created the WebView because other sites are also loaded in it. Anyway I will take a closer look to your answer.